# obtaining an object with the max value respect of a field in a Scala Seq

Tags: scala, playframework, scala-collections

Cycle is an object that has a field called cycleNumber respect of which I want to get the Cycle object with the max cycleNumber. To do that I am trying:

```
def maxCycle(xs: Seq[Cycle]): Cycle = xs match {
  /*this means xs CAN NOT BE EMPTY*/
    case Seq(x: Cycle) => x
    case x :: y :: rest => maxCycle( (if (x.cycleNumber.getOrElse(0) > y.cycleNumber.getOrElse(0)) x else y ) :: rest )
```

However, I am getting a match error and I believe this is respect of the latest command as the respective table has 2 rows for the Cycle object.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you show us an example where your code fails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get max value from a Seq you can use sortBy, maxBy, reduce or fold

```
case class Cycle(cycleNumber:Option[Int])
val cycles = Seq(Cycle(Option(4)), Cycle(Option(1)), Cycle(Option(8)), Cycle(Option(8)))

// sortBy + lastOption because max fails if seq is empty
val max = cycles.sortBy(_.cycleNumber).lastOption

// reduceOption if seq is empty
vao max2 = cycles.reduceOption { (a, b) => if(a.cycleNumber.getOrElse(0) > b.cycleNumber.getOrElse(0)) a else b }

// or if seq is not empty
val max3 = cycles.maxBy(_.cycleNumber)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def maxCycle(xs: Seq[Cycle]): Cycle = {
    xs.map(a => (a, a.cycleNumber.getOrElse(0))).maxBy(_._2)._1
}
```

A simple implementation:

1. convert Seq[Cycle] to Seq[(Cycle, Int)] each tuple's ._1 being the cycle itself and ._2 being its cycleNumber (0 if None)
2. get tuple with max cycleNumber
3. return that tuple's first element (._1) or cycle the itself